# Set a pointer field of any type to a new value via reflect - not assignable to type

Tags: go, reflection

I have an incomplete data `struct` with some fields of any type, and I have an update data  `struct` which shall be used to complete all `nil` fields in my incomplete data:

```golang
func main() {
    var incomplete any = struct {
        ID      string
        Name    *string
        Address *string
    }{
        ID:      "Some ID",
        Name:    toPtr("some Name"),
        Address: nil,
    }

    var update any = struct {
        Name    *string
        Address *string
    }{
        Name:    toPtr("Other name which won't be applied"),
        Address: toPtr("my/location"),
    }

    existingV := reflect.ValueOf(incomplete)
    existingT := reflect.TypeOf(incomplete)
    for i := 0; i < existingV.NumField(); i++ {
        existingField := existingV.Field(i)
        if existingField.IsValid() {
            if existingField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                if existingField.IsNil() {
                    existingFieldT := existingT.Field(i)
                    newValue := getUpdatedField(update, existingFieldT.Name, existingFieldT.Type)

                    // Attempt 1: will fail with reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value                
                    // reflect.ValueOf(incomplete).FieldByName(existingFieldT.Name).Set(reflect.ValueOf(newValuePtr))

                    // Attempt 2: reflect.Set: value of type *interface {} is not assignable to type *string
                    v := reflect.ValueOf(&incomplete).Elem()
                    tmp := reflect.New(v.Elem().Type()).Elem()
                    tmp.Set(v.Elem())
                    byName := tmp.FieldByName(existingFieldT.Name)
                    newValuePtr := &newValue
                    newReflectValue := reflect.ValueOf(newValuePtr)
                    // newReflectValueConv := newReflectValue.Convert(byName.Type()) // panic
                    byName.Set(newReflectValue) // panic 
                    v.Set(tmp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// for the sake of completeness, probably not relevant
func getUpdatedField(updatedData any, fieldName string, fieldType reflect.Type) (value any) {
    updatedT := reflect.TypeOf(updatedData)
    for i := 0; i < updatedT.NumField(); i++ {
        if updatedT.Field(i).Name == fieldName {
            v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(updatedData)).Field(i)
            if fieldType == updatedT.Field(i).Type && v.CanInterface() {
                return v.Interface()
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func toPtr(str string) *string {
    return &str
}
```

The second attempt is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421976/panic-reflect-call-of-reflect-value-fieldbyname-on-interface-value). It fails with `value of type *interface {} is not assignable to type *string`. Trying to convert it first with `newReflectValue.Convert(byName.Type())` will panic with the same error. I also tinkered around with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324466/5767484), but no avail either.

How to achieve a proper conversion or assign the new value another way?

Comment: This very much feels like an X-Y problem. I'd start with embedding the update types, and perhaps implement a `Merge` or `Combine` method of some sort on the types. No need for reflection, and you'll end up with nice and clean, maintainable code

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for your response! What to you mean with "embedding the update types"? Like working with explicit, known types? That's where I'm coming from but this "data augmentation" service becomes more and more bloated with almost duplicate code for all kind of incoming data types (and the corresponding update data queries from a remote GraphQL service). So now I try to find a more generalized solution.

Comment: Hm, what's actually true is that I could just render the finished object a `map[string]any` and assign all values there. I mean, this is a remote service, the final data structure will be marshaled to JSON anyway. This would still mean lots of reflections, but only for reading, and I could avoid the `Value#Set` call. And, in theory, even the incoming objects could be mere `maps` ...